# Change month cells size in Angular Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, calendar

I am using the GitHub project Angular Bootstrap Calendar that you may find here: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar.

I am using CalendarMonthView and this is great for PC and Mobile. I have problems with my iPad Pro 1366x1024 resolution. I can't change cells size, in particular i want to change height of class cal-cell1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cellmodifier is your friend. here [link] (https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#!?example=cell-modifier)